# Spoiler code with onclick and 2 conditions

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I've got a spoiler-code on my Homepage.
The Code looks like this:

```
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none"> 
HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div> 
<a display="initial" 
   id="button" 
   title="Click to show/hide content" 
   type="button" 
   onclick="if(document.getElementById('spoiler')                     
                       .style.display=='none') {
               document.getElementById('spoiler')                                    
                       .style.display=''
            }else{
               document.getElementById('spoiler')               
                       .style.display='none'
            }">
   Show hidden content
</a>
```

What I want to do now is quite simple:
After clicking on the element "button", the hidden content shall be shown and the anchor `<a>` shall become invisible.

So what I am looking for is:
onclick: if element "spoiler" is on display=none AND element "button" is on display=initial THEN the element "spoiler" shall change to display=initial AND element "button" shall change to display=none

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code in **jquery** will solve your problem. I hope this is what you wanted.

```
$('#button').click(function() {
        $('#spoiler').css('display', 'block');
      $(this).hide();
    });
```

I have demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mayank_shubham/surw65nm/) as well.

A **JavaScript** only solution will be as follows:

```
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none"> 
HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div> 
<a display="initial" id="button" title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display='block';
  document.getElementById('button').style.display='none'">Show hidden content</a>
```

Comment: Not sure if OP wants a `jQuery` solution.

Comment: I added a javascript solution as well @Aziz

Answer (score 1):

Try following code. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/r955q61j/).

```
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none" onclick="this.style.display='none';">
   HIDDEN CONTENT HERE
</div>
<a display="initial" id="button" title="Click to show/hide content" type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('spoiler').style.display='block';">Show hidden content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`display="initial"` isn't a valid attribute. Also, putting all of that code in the `onclick` attribute prevents you from reusing the code in other spoiler blocks. The best solution is to use a `script` tag for separation of concerns and reusability.

Here's the bare-bones of what you need:

```
<div id="spoiler" style="display:none">HIDDEN CONTENT HERE</div> 
<a onclick="showSpoiler(this,'spoiler')">Show hidden content</a>
<script>
function showSpoiler(buttonNode, spoilerId) {
    document.getElementById(spoilerId).style.display='block';
    buttonNode.style.display='none';
}
</script>
```